# Breaking a SVG Line

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I work with SVG and d3js and I want a line with values like:

0,10 -
10,20 -
20,25 -
30,40 -
40,50

So, for example, I want a line with these points but between the point "20,25" and "30,40" I want nothing (or a line but transparent). And I don't want to have two lines.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to insert the 'path' element for this.

```
d3.select('svg')
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M0,10 L10,20 L20,25 M30,40 L40,50')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
```

Comment: You can also have relative positioning here if you specify lowercase 'm' and 'l' commands - or even mix the both approaches